# Google chrome search results different view

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm using latest version of Google Chrome in my android. Recently, the view of Google search results have changed.

I don't like this view because address is  in a grey color background and search results are in full black and white . I tried all settings to figure out why this change has happened.

It's really disgusting seeing this view

How to go back to previous view? 
Here is the link for image for more clarity

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Google might be doing some A/B testing with their UI - iirc they did that a few years ago with black/dark/light blue shades for links. Could you try using incognito, another device and/or another internet connection? Then you can work out how they are targeting you - in any case it's probably temporary.